# Should beginning programmers get their own SE "Beginning Programming"?

Tags: discussion, new-users, site-proposal

I'm not sure what it is, but the number of super beginner programmer questions appears to be increasing dramatically on SO recently.

Here's one I saw today:

- [How to add an integer to each element in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304408/add-an-integer-to-each-element-python)

Ouch! Really? How to do a loop? These things should be learned in any tutorial.

Now I'm all for introducing new people to programming, but if you don't know what "Stack Overflow" means maybe you shouldn't be asking a question there.

So I vote to give them their own SE Island, "Beginning Programming", so we can have a safe and encouraging place for these types of questions.

Who's with me?

Comment: So in other words, you're proposing `DoMyProgrammingHomeworkForMe.SE`... I pass.  We should be encouraging _good_ questions.

Comment: oh well, just an idea.  There has to be something that can be done to improve question quality.  There really seems to be an increase in these kind of questions lately.

Comment: How do you encourage good questions to a new user who has nothing invested in the site?

Comment: @JeffMercado Also if you look at the example question, users with over 2000 rep are answering it, and no one has yet to "encourage" doing something better or close it.  It's not a "bad" question, it's just *very* beginner.

Comment: perhaps a better proposal would be to screen "first" questions of new users with the default username?

Comment: @monkut There's a [review tab](http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers) for just that (10k only, I think)

Comment: And we still get these questions?

Comment: @MichaelMrozek nope, it is accessible since you got 2k

Answer (score 4):

**I don't think the answer to getting people who are clueless to have a clue is to isolate them from the pros.**

All that will do is keep them from learning.  If you have a group in need of help, you don't put them aside to be ignored, which is what will happen.

If you put all the "new" people into their own isolated site, what do  you expect the outcome will be?  Obviously most of the experienced folks will not go to that site because they won't want to go out of their way to answer really basic questions about variable declaration or finding syntax errors in big blocks of code or whatever.

The incentive to help these people now is it's easy rep on SO.  If these questions are in their own site then that motivation disappears.